# How to indent a buffer in ESS?

Tags: emacs, r, elisp, ess

ESS allows us to indent a line and an expression. Is there a key binding for indenting a buffer? If not, can we create it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated by others you could mark the whole buffer `C-x h` and then indent the region with `C-M-\`

You could also put something along these lines in your `.emacs` file:

```
(defun my-indent-buffer()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))))

(global-set-key "\C-cib" 'my-indent-buffer)
```

This has the benefit of remembering your point.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about a buffer but you can mark a region and then use `C-M-\` on it.

Comment: Ah. As always with Emacs, one learns something new every day. Or I guess one should. :)